# What do I type to produce the command symbol (⌘) in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, internationalization, keyboard

What combination of keys do I press to produce the command symbol (⌘) on Mac OS X?

(I copied the above symbol from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_key.)

Comment: If you like to add it to your non Unicode HTML-sources, you can use the following HTML-Command: &#8984; . http://fenon.de/apple-befehlstaste-%E2%8C%98-in-blog-artikeln-verwenden/

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you need to find the name and hex code of *that special character you don't know what to call it*, try [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/).

Comment: isn't it alt shift m

Answer (score 300, accepted):

If you're just looking for the Unicode versions of Mac OS X keys, you can use this Apple support document to copy and paste them:

> Mac keyboard shortcuts
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

- `⌘` Command (or Cmd)
- `⇧` Shift
- `⌥` Option (or Alt)
- `⌃` Control (or Ctrl)

---

More generally, Mac OS X provides a pane to insert special characters. You'll find it under Edit -> Emoji and Symbols in any program that takes text input. The Command key symbol can be found by searching for it's name "place of interest". To insert the character, double click it.

[image]

---

If you're *really* hardcore and are looking for a way to type the character by entering the Unicode hex code, this is possible:

1. Go into System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources, click "+", scroll to "others", select "Unicode Hex Input" and click "Add"

   [image]
2. From the input source selector in the menu bar, select "Unicode Hex Input"

   [image]
3. To enter a Unicode character, hold down <kbd>option</kbd> and type the 4-digit hex code for the character and it will be inserted. In this case, it would be <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>.

Comment: Wow, I was sure that would be some option-key way to type a `⌘`. But there isn't!  I just looked through every possible variation of the keyboard viewer and it's just... not... there!

Comment: starting with Lion, to see the Technical Symbols in the Special Characters window you'll need to click into Settings to "Customize List..." and add it to your view.

Comment: Thanks @GraehamF, I've updated to an archived copied.  Still works!

Comment: @Will indeed, cannot find it any more

Comment: In El Capitan, select "Other" in the Language list and then select "Unicode Hex Input"

Comment: @Ken is correct - the feature seems to have moved to this location since the question was originally answered.  His comment worked for me in OS X Sierra as well.

Comment: On newer systems. Open viewer, open the setting dropdown on top > Customize List... > (scroll down) > Check Technical Symbols.

Comment: @bauerMusic, what do u mean by newer systems please? I'm using Mac OS X 10.12.4. Also, please elaborate more on what you're talking about.

Comment: @nyxee On OSX (macOS) 10.12.4, these symbols are not there by default. One needs to open the viewer, then open the settings (the littler wheal on top left) Customize List... > (scroll down) > Check Technical Symbols. I was not allowed to post images here, sorry..

Comment: @bauerMusic "open the viewer" - which viewer are you talking about?

Comment: @JoshJ The 'viewer': On the top right of the screen, just to the left of the 'time', there should be a language menu with an icon (depends on the language). The menu will have the languages (if more than one) followed by "Show Emoji and Symbols" and "Show Keyboard Viewer". If it's not there, it can be added from the settings (Keyboard preferences -> Input sources -> (Check) Show Input menu...)

Comment: "Place of interest" hmm… interesting name for the "Command key" :p

Comment: Once you have the symbol (⌘) on your clipboard, map it to a Keyboard>Text replace string, such as A!.

Comment: Isn't there some way to put the keyboard input source onto the toolbar?

Comment: `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources, click "+"`: I do not have a +

Answer (score 155):

An answer for OSX Lion (circa 2014):

You can also type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (aka <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>) to bring up the characters menu, then start typing to search, and search for `place of interest`, then press enter to start selecting them, then tab to the correct result, then enter again to insert it.

[image: Place of interest in Character Viewer]

Sounds like a lot, but it can really be narrowed down to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, typing `pla`, and then two presses of <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer, as it can be done entirely with keyboard and doesn't require any special setup. `^-⌘-<space>, p, l, <enter><enter>`. Once you've used it once, you don't even need to type the `pl` next time.

Comment: On OS X 10.8.5 here the shortcut seems to be ⌘⌥T, but I can't find where that's defined. `^-⌘-<space>` doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: `^-⌘-<space>` is not working for me on OSX 10.12.4. I get the popup with the symbols. but when i click on them, nothing is displayed in any Text editor. I also tried to enter `p, l` first but nothing happened.

Comment: It _used_ to be ⌥⌘T, but they changed it. I used System Preferences to switch it back. (:

Comment: Character Viewer & ⌘+^+Space

Comment: This can also be used for the option key `⌥` by opening up the emoji/character viewer as described and typing `option`. I have no idea where the shift `⇧` or control `⌃` key characters are though. (Control is technically a different character than the caret `^`.)

Comment: @Joel Mellon [@rymo's comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/what-do-i-type-to-produce-the-command-symbol-in-mac-os-x#comment88788_4077) in another answer is the key. Use the expanded view in the Character Viewer, click the gear icon in the upper left, choose Customize List and add the *Technical Symbols* group. And if you want to go the hard route and search for the character names, the Shift icon is "Upwards White Arrow", Control is "Up Arrowhead", and Caps Lock is "Upwards Right Arrow From Bar".

Answer (score 59):

I also found it hard to find a straight answer for this, so I just went into System Preferences > Keyboard > Text (or Text Input) > Text Replacements and created a use symbol and text substitution option where when I type (cmd) it replaces it with the command symbol.

Comment: In Mavericks at least, this is under `System Preferences > Keyboard > Text`.

Comment: Great solution.  Substitution characters [here](http://ipadhelp.com/everything-else/mac-keyboard-symbols-for-apple-computers/).  The characters shown can be copied and pasted for each substitution.

Comment: Love this solution. just copy and paste this ... ⌘ into the "With" column.

Comment: Is there anything else i need to do for this to work please? I went to Keyboard > Text, added cmd and ⌘, went to a text editor, I typed cmd followed by the Enter key, but the cmd did not magically turn into the ⌘ symbol. I'm using OSX 10.12.4.

Comment: This is a more usable solution than any higher answers, should be accepted answer IMO :)

Answer (score 21):

For future reference, you can copy and paste from here:

```
⌃  <- Control
⌥  <- Option aka alt
⌘  <- Command
⇧  <- Shift
```

These are rendered like this:

[image]

Comment: How do I create the little section you have in the grey segment above?

Comment: Just 4 spaces before each line, and an empty line above and beneath the section

Comment: No, I mean the character itself. The Control, Alt, and Command icons?

Comment: @HarryMcGovern For how to type the Command icon, this question might help you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/what-do-i-type-to-produce-the-command-symbol-in-mac-os-x

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55727/where-can-i-find-the-unicode-symbols-for-mac-functional-keys-command-shift-e

Comment: You can use the `Preferences → Keyboard → Text` settings. Assign a keyword for each of these symbols in the 'replace' column (you will need to click on the `+` button at the bottom of the list) and then copy/paste symbol from Chris' answer on the 'with' column. I have used `kcmd` for ⌘, `kctrl` for ⌃, `kopt` for ⌥ and `kshft` for ⇧. It's basically 'k' followed by the commonly used name of the symbol. `k` stands for 'key'.

Comment: @JonSchneider The link you have provided links to the question we're on now.

Answer (score 15):

You can also add Your favourite characters to "press and hold" key behaviour.

[image]

Here's explanation how to do it on apple stackexchange: [How to add characters to the press and hold character picker in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion)

Keep in mind that this is done inside `System` directory, so be careful and remember that there's a chance of losing Your setup after upgrading the OS.

Answer (score 11):

If you have [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html), one can also make a snippet for it, ala [Dr. Drang](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/06/a-couple-of-textexpander-thingies/).

[image: Abbreviation for typing ⌘]

He also has a [Keyboard Library](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/downloads/Keyboard.textexpander) with snippets for a host of keyboard symbols available.

Answer (score 10):

With the document open, place the cursor where you want the symbol,
Open the Character Viewer as described above. Type "Place of Interest" in the character viewer search field. It shows up on at the bottom of the window. Double click it and it shows up where you placed your cursor. Save it to your favorites in the Character Viewer window to make it easier to find next time.
This under OS 10.9.1 "Mavericks"

Answer (score 8):

This is the simple way on how to do it.

1. Download [BetterTouchTool](http://boastr.de)
2. Open the application
3. Select 'keyboard'
4. Click Add New Shortcut
5. Set keyboard shortcut to '<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'
6. Set trigger predefined action to 'Paste predefined text'
7. Copy '⌘' into the box.
8. Click Ok

Now whenever BetterTouchTool is open all you have to do is press '<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>' and it automatically types the '⌘' symbol.

You only have to do steps one to eight once.

Answer (score 8):

**How to type the modifier key glyphs on MacOs:**

1. "control+command+space" in any application
2. type "up arrowhead" to find: `⌃` (control)
3. type "option" to find: `⌥` (option / alt)
4. type "place of interest" to find: `⌘` (command / super)
5. type "upwards white arrow" to find `⇧` (shift)

Comment: I can't find shift `⇧` for the life of me.

Comment: that's "upwards white arrow" or `&#8679;` I found it on https://www.amp-what.com/

Comment: Oh nice! Typing "upward" into the emoji viewer, pulls it up. It's quite a bit fatter than when rendered in the font that inline code blocks do here, but it appears to be the same char (⇧) or `⇧`.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth (on OSX and maybe Windows): In Libre Offices's Writer I found the symbol as the 5th entry in both the LiHei Pro and LiSong fonts.

Answer (score 3):

The Mac **Characters** popup is definitely the straightforward solution if you need to insert some chacters once in a while. But if you regularly need to use Unicode characters which are not present on your keyboard then a radical solution would be creating your own keyboard layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) that will map those characters to your physical keys.

The app is only used to create an OSX compliant layout file (XML or bundle) which can then be added via *Preferences* > *Keyboard* > *Input Sources* > <kbd>＋</kbd>.

With Ukelele you can clone your existing standard keyboard (***File > New from current input source***), and remap any of the keys to your liking.

In the default keyboard layout holding the **Option** key <kbd>⌥</kbd> in combination with any letter/symbol key will insert extended math characters which normally are never used, e.g. `œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπ“‘«æ…¬˚∆˙©ƒ∂ßåΩ≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥÷¿˘¯Â˜ı◊Ç˛¸ÅÍÎÏ˝ÓÔÒÚÆ»’”∏Øˆ¨Áˇ‰„„`. Holding down Shift+Option will give you yet another set of special characters.

With Ukelele you can remap **Option+key** and **Shift+Option+key** to anything you like including Unicode emoji characters.

Here is an example of assigning <kbd>⌘</kbd> to the **Option+c** combination:

[image: Ukelele remap keys]

You can pick the required character for mapping using the built-in *Characters* app as explained in other answers.

> <sub>Note: If you have a non-US keyboard (i.e. non-ANSI) you might need to set the correct type under **View > Keyboard Type** > **Coding**: *ISO*</sub>

While this might be overkill for a single character, it actually makes sense when you want to tweak other things on your keyboard and have complete control.

Once you have created your custom layout you can use it on any number of macs by simply copying it to `~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts` and then adding it in *Preferences* without the need to use any third party apps. The layout can be installed directly from Ukelele via the **File** > **Install** option. Once installed you still need to add it manually via **Preferences** > **Keyboard**.

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I am not affiliated with the app author. I simply found the app very useful in solving some issues with my keyboard which had some keys in the 'wrong' place.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

**[Answer for people who type Japanese text]**

Japanese IMEs are surprisingly good at finding characters.

If you are already routinely typing in Japanese, then the easiest way the get the `⌘` character is to type `k` `o` `m` `a` `n` `d` `o`, then press `tab` and `return` to select the character in the suggestions popup that appears:

[image]

That's 9 keystrokes but:

- Much easier to remember than an hexadecimal code (plus you don't need to remember how to enter hexadecimal codes)
- You don't need to install or configure anything that you don't have already.
- You don't need to start any program.
- IMEs spend a lot of effort making sure they are usable absolutely everywhere, so it works in any text field of any program.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using keyboardmaestro simply create a macro in the Global Macro Group (if you want to have the macro available globally) as follows:

1. Create new macro
2. Give the macro a name like "insert ⌘"
3. Add "Typed String Trigger": =cmd
4. Add "New Action" and choose "Insert Text by Pasting"

Now whenever you type the string "=cmd" a "⌘" will be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

For my money, PopChar remains the best character/glyph selector utility for finding, browsing, and pasting characters into text.

It has been a Mac essential since the 90s at least.

https://www.ergonis.com/products/popcharx/

Comment: I remember that! hahaha! old school :)  … Nowadays I use https://www.amp-what.com/ or `FontGoggles.app` here: https://fontgoggles.org/

Answer (score 1):

Hit `Fn` then type "interest".

[image: macOS emoji picker]

Comment: This seems the easiest way using Ventura 13.6 in 2023.  Also type _option_ to get ⌥.   The used symbol then goes into "frequently used" so a press of fn (_globe_) and click of the mouse takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you writing out keyboard shortcuts for Mac users, I'd recommend using the Apple Style Guide (https://help.apple.com/asg/mac/2013/) way of doing this so whatever you write is consistent with other Apple documentation. In this case you would type out `Command` rather then use the ⌘ symbol. So, for example Paste would be:

```
Command-V
```

Alternately you could use Key Graphics.

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

The thing is if you are typing it out always use `Command`.

Comment: This does not answer the question "What combination of keys do I press to produce the command symbol (⌘) on Mac OS X?"

Answer (score -2):

I normally use "<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>" to generate a  Symbol.

Instead of using a ⌘ Symbol whenever writing anything which requires keystrokes / shortcuts because for most of the time that I have been using Apple computers it was called the "apple key" . (and the symbol physically written on the key was a  and not a ⌘)

Comment: This is not a bad workaround! I usually pronounce the key "apple" anyway.

Comment: The Apple symbol will normally only display on Apple devices, as it is not included in standard fonts on other platforms.

Comment: On other devices, this shows up as a box with an x through it (kind of like this⌧)

Comment: This does not answer the question "What combination of keys do I press to produce the command symbol (⌘) on Mac OS X?"

Comment: The Apple character doesn't even render correctly on Macs half the time. eg. focus the URL bar in Chrome and type `⇧` + `⌥` + `K` and see the good old question mark in a diamond.

Comment: Apple has not put the  symbol on the Command key on a keyboard since 2007. Prior to that, It has born both logos and has been known officially as the "Command key" since the introduction of the Mac in 1984.