# How to enter in the apple symbol not in a web browser?

Tags: keyboard

How can I enter in the enter in the Apple symbol () in an application such as text edit?

IIRC, Safari automatically converts this symbol when it sees the text `&apple;`.

Update: Does it exist in the Edit > Special Characters... list?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/how-do-i-type-a-command-character-in-mac-os-x

Comment: It's worth noting that [this symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U+F8FF) is non-standard; it will be interpreted differently by different fonts.

Comment: Windows machines normally will not have any fonts that display his character, only Apple products.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neil's <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> might work in (presumably) the US, but the exact combination is keyboard layout specific. In addition, some keyboard layouts — Thai, for example — might not even have the symbol available.

E.g. I'm using a Finnish keyboard layout and  is typed simply by <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

To find this and other symbol shortcuts, you can enable the keyboard & symbol menulet from `Preferences` → `Keyboard` and use the menulet to open a virtual keyboard. Pressing any modifier key, or modifier key combination, will change the keys on the virtual keyboard accordingly. For example, here is how the virtual keyboard looks with Finnish layout while option/alt is being pressed:

[image: finnish keyboard layout while pressing option]

To find the  from `Special characters` menu the fastest way is to type `f8ff` to the search box (this is its unicode-code; the  hasn't any other name assigned).

Other way is to change the view to `glyphs` or to `code tables`<sup>[1]</sup> from the drop-down list and browse the for the symbol manually — but this is not exactly user-friendly or fast, unless you know where to look for.

---

[1]: I don't know for sure if these are exact translations as my UI is also in Finnish. However, the items are (respectively) last and third-last in the list.

Comment: Is there any way to find out how to type the symbol given a specific keyboard layout? I'm using a custom layout which I created and noticed that Shift-Option-K only works if I switch back to the US layout. Thus, it would be useful if there was an easy way to figure out which keyboard shortcut I need to use on my custom layout.

Comment: @Senseful if you've enabled the `Keyboard & symbol` menulet from `Preferences` -> `Keyboard` you can use it to open a virtual keyboard. While pressing any modifier keys the pictured virtual keyboard will change accordingly.

Comment: @koiyu: that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Why is your alt character in the kbd tags upside down?

Comment: Please note that not all keyboard layouts have the  symbol. For example, Thai layout does not.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will type the Apple logo.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, do you know if it exists in Edit > Special Characters?

Comment: I can't find it there.

Comment: It's actually not in Unicode. It's just a Private Use Area character (F8FF) in some of Apple's fonts, like Lucida Grande and Monaco. Some Linux fonts have a Tux on that same code point.