# Customising Lion’s accented letters

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add characters to the press and hold character picker in OS X Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion)

I’m slightly disappointed by Lion’s iOS inspired feature to show a selection of accented characters on key hold.

On a German keyboard, when pressing <kbd>a</kbd>, I am able to choose between `ä`,  `â`, `à`, `á`, `æ`, `ã`, `å`, `ā`. So far so nice.

However, I feel some characters are missing. There is no `ç` (although I could type this one using <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>), no `ğ` and no `ł` either. On the other hand the letter `ń` is shown (which like `ł` is more or less only used in Polish) but to which OS X does not show an upper case version. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> yields no results.

Is there some way to enhance and expand this set of letters with own additions?

Comment: This isn't an answer per se, but in the System Preferences under International and then the Input Menu you can have the OS display a menubar menu called "Character Palette". The Character Palette shows all the characters available, allows you to insert them, and allows you to build lists of favorites.

Comment: Again, an inconsistent behavior.... I don't get how the developers could forget to implement access to `ç` by holding the c-key. Good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved recently elsewhere in the forum:

[How to add characters to the press and hold character picker in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion)

Comment: Would you like me to merge this account with the other? Your rep will then be combined...