# MacOS Catalina keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

After Catalina upgrade I have noticed my keyboard layout is different. I was using Croatian (e.g. Y was Z, @ was opt+shift+2).

Now it is switched to "Croatian - PC" which resembles Windows keyboard layout (Y is still Z, @ is opt+v).

There is another option, which is "Croatian" and is similar to what I had before, but with some changes (Y is Y, @ is opt+2).

Is there a way without some external tool and re-mappings to revert my keyboard to what it was before?

Comment: Same problem here.
After update for Catalina my USB Microsoft Wired 600 (Portuguese), have a completely different mapping. E.g.:
```
< now is §
> now is ±
\ now is <
| now is >
€ now is æ
``` And so on... I already look for drivers in MS website, but I just found for win 10.
I'm also looking for a solution for remap.

Comment: @djayor  Your problem sounds different.  What exactly do you have on your list in system preferences/keyboard/input sources?  What "flag" is showing at the top right of the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have put of copy of the Croatian layout from an earlier MacOS, named "Old Croatian", [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouitfghr412ge86/Old%20Croatian.keylayout?dl=0) and a copy of the Croatian PC layout [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqrwj165rnr0x52/Old%20Croatian%20PC.keylayout?dl=0). Hopefully one of them will help.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Is it possible to import this file without Ukulele?

Comment: @Norgul Sure, you just put .keylayout files in Home/Library/Keyboard Layouts, logout/login, and activate via the input sources preference pane.  They will be in the "others" folder.

Comment: That worked great. Do you know if it is possible to use one of the "other"-s as a primary input method? I can't seem to remove what was primary before, even though I have added this new one on the list (and am using it)

Comment: @Norgul  Have a look at this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44913/make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-the-system-default-even-for-the-login-screen/44916#44916

Comment: Moving to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` instead of `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts` helped. Thanks

Comment: @Tom Gewecke I have 2 flags, Irish for my internal keyboard of my MacBook Pro.
And another Portuguese for my USB keyboard. Well I resolved my problem editing the layout in Ukulele, and moving the .keylayout to /Library/Keyboard Layouts. Unfortunately the "<" are not in the correct place, because the specific key in the left side of "Z" is not editable by Ukulele.

Comment: @djayor You are wrong about the key next to z.  When in Ukelele, do View > Keyboard Type and change ANSI to ISO.