# How to make a Ukelele custom keyboard the sole keyboard layout system wide and default—even on the login screen on Ventura, or Monterey

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey, ventura

None of the old techniques work, and the old questions are completely outdated since Big Sur, or Monterey. (see: [Make a custom keyboard layout the system default — even for the login screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44913/make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-the-system-default-even-for-the-login-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1))

The question is simple, but the solution may a difficult one, if possible at all.

Comment: Tried this one?   https://heylon.ca/how-to-permanently-switch-default-keyboard-at-login-for-macos/

Comment: Also search/ask at Ukelele users if not done already:  https://groups.google.com/g/ukelele-users?pli=1