# Accessing certain diacritical vowel characters in the Spanish layout in Mac OS X

Tags: mac, keyboard, internationalization, mapping

I need the following Portuguese characters: ã, õ.

I write in Spanish/Portuguese all the time, but I am used to the Spanish keyboard layout. I can do anything but write the mentioned characters.

I do NOT want to constantly switch between Spanish/Portuguese layouts.

I would like to remap the key combinations: "option+a" and "option+o" to ã and õ respectively. Right now on those keys, I have these (å and ø) which are almost useless to me.

I cannot find a way to map those key combinations to my desired characters.

Can someone please help me? I downloaded keyremap4mac, but couldn't find a way to do it. Do you know a piece of software that would let me define the combination and the desired characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option/alt + ñ on the Spanish ISO layout, followed by a or o gives you ã and õ.

To make a custom layout, use Ukelele

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

PS If you are running 10.7, you can also get those characters by holding down the a and o keys until the Character Picker popup menu appears.

Comment: @Santiago I recently posted an answer with some more details on how to create custom keyboard layouts — you might be interested: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45402/4408

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to type "ã" and "õ" on the Spanish keyboard.

The usual <kbd>ñ</kbd> key has a second function, which is technically referred to as a *dead (diacritical) key*. Hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while you type the <kbd>ñ</kbd> key. This will produce a tilde "~" hanging in the air. Then immediately release the two keys and type the "a" key and you will get an "ã". The same method works to produce an "õ".

You can see the diacritical key in orange below.

[image]

Comment: This is of course a more detailed explanation of the same thing that Tom Gewecke wrote above.