# MacBook Pro Factory reset started installing OS X El Capitan but now OS X Mavericks installer appears

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac-appstore

I tried to reset my MacBook Pro to the factory settings so I booted with CMD+R and erased the disk then I proceed to reinstall OS X El Capitan, but I was at my friend's house and the Internet was super slow, so I canceled and turned off the machine to do it at home. Now at home, I booted with CMD+R but instead of going to the OS X El Capitan installer like last time it contacted Apple through the Internet and presented me the OS X Mavericks installer. What to do?

Answer (score 4):

Install Mavericks and upgrade it to El Capitan. When your do so it should create a proper recovery partition. Reboot into that and erase the disk and re-install El Capitan.

Comment: I would get a USB drive and make an El Capitan installer rather than mess with the erase/re-install steps. It's already erased and a clean mavericks instal will turn into a quite clean El Cap install in my experience. +1 despite the minor quibble.

Comment: i just upgraded it, but it says it has 10 gb as others. Why?