# Persisting old name of Mac during file transfer

Tags: macos, hosts

I'm using macOS Ventura 13.4.1.

Before migrating to my current Mac desktop, I changed the name of its predecessor from "MyMac" to "MyMacOLD" and then did the migration from TimeMachine.

The new Mac is named "MyMac".

Yet when I use file sharing from this new "MyMac" to a MacBook and transfer files from "MyMac" to the MacBook using a file comparison/transfer app (namely, VisualDiffer), each time I try a comparison of corresponding folders on the two machines, I get a pop-up error "There was a problem connecting to the server "MyMacOLD".

If I just dismiss that pop-up, it pops up again; dismissing it again now allows the comparison of folders, and subsequent syncing via the app, to proceed.

The Mac's SystemSettings > General > About shows the name as "MyMac"

The situation persists even after I used all the steps shown at https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Setting-the-Mac-hostname-or-computer-name-from-the-terminal.html that use the terminal command `scutil` to set the name to "MyMac" (without the quotes, of course), including the restart.

**Question:** Where is that name "MyMacOLD" being picked up from, and how can I fix it to be what my Mac is supposed to be named, "MyMac"?

Comment: There are three names using `scutil` that need to be set.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303411/119271) for more details.

Comment: On the old Mac, which name is shown in System Settings? Which name is shown in Terminal?

Comment: @nohillside: The machine that had been named "MyMacOLD" is long gone, back to Apple in a trade-in. On the desktop Mac which I'm using as server for file sharing, the name in SystemSettings is MyMac.

Comment: @Allan: Yes, as I said, I used `scutil` to set all three to MyMac. And that's what `scutil --get ....` shows for ComputerName, HostName, and LocalHostName.  In System Settings > General > Sharing, at the bottom, Local hostname displays as MyMac.local.

Comment: Did you restart your router since the old Mac has gone? If not, this might be worth a try.

Comment: @nohillside: I have restarted the router (actually, both a cable gateway and a router) since the old Mac has been gone, and more than once, due to outages!

Comment: What do you get when you type `hostname` in Terminal?

Comment: The router works by MAC (Media Access Control and not Macintosh) address so your new Mac would get a completely different IP address and hostname from your old one.  It can’t be the router.  Did you change the [computer name in Sharing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/322329/119271) as well?

Comment: @Allan: In Ventura, the Sharing settings look different from what you linked to. Under File Sharing, there's no field to type in a name. The information icon takes me to a pop-up saying, "Other users can access shared folders on this computer, and administrators all volumes, at smb://10.0.0.8. So no _name_ shown there!

Comment: @Allan: in Ventura, at the bottom of the Sharing panel, the Local hostname is, as I said, MyMac.local.

Comment: I’m on an iPad and doing this from memory, so please bear with me.  In Ventura, it’s under *Settings → General → About*. Confirm that it’s accurate there as well.

Comment: @Allan: Yes, correct in System Settings > General > About.