# Autochoose for press and hold?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Is there a way to change the press and hold character picker in a way that it automatically choose a certain character.

I'm German using an US keyboard (on purpose, I don't want to switch back to a German one) and if I press and hold 'a' I get a lot of options. I don't care about any of them but the 'ä'. I know how to eliminate the other choices (thanks to [How to add characters to the press and hold character picker in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion)) but I don't even want to chose. I want to hold and press the 'a' and would love for the 'ä' to just appear without me having to choose it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with press and hold, but you can press:   option + "u" then "a" to get "ä". I find it quicker than pressing and holding the key.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. The English keyboard is optimized with the set of accents that English writers use the most. (For example, the U key's default is Û in English and Ú in Spanish.)

The German keyboard may provide a more relevant set of defaults.

Comment: I can change the defaults and deleted every choice besides the 'ä' but I want to make it not only show up but be inserted immediately