# What are the key-names for the PressAndHold.app keyboard plists?

Tags: macos, internationalization

To avoid ambiguity in this question I will use `key` to mean a plist-dictionary-key (look-up string); and <kbd>key</kbd> to mean a button on your keyboard.

---

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/44928/25230) to another question identified a great way to edit the special characters you can insert using the press-and-hold method on your keyboard.

You can edit the `Keyboard-xx.plist` files of the `PressAndHold.app` to add your characters to existing press-and-hold <kbd>keys</kbd>. The plist dictionary `keys` for each press-and-holdable <kbd>key</kbd> look like this: `<key>Roman-Accent-a</key>`, and `<key>Roman-Accent-A</key>`, etc. but if you want to add some press-and hold characters to a number <kbd>key</kbd>, or a punctuation <kbd>key</kbd> then you need to know the `key` name for the dictionary in order to add it.

I want to add press-and-hold characters for the <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>keys</kbd> and possibly others, I have tried the following formats for the `key` names in the plist file:

```
2
Number-2
Roman-Accent-2
```

None of these add a press-and-hold popover for the <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>key</kbd>. What are the correct `key` names for all of my keyboard <kbd>keys</kbd> that I can add in `Keyboard-en.plist`?

Answer (score 2):

I have actually the same question, but this may help someone that is trying to figure this out.

I found here, that the name is probably Roman-Accent-2:
https://github.com/skalnik/dotfiles/blob/master/osx/emoji-expansions.plist

as this code is used:

```
<key>Roman-Accent-1</key>
<dict>
<key>Direction</key>
<string>right</string>
<key>Keycaps</key>
<string>1 1</string>
<key>Strings</key>
<string>1 1</string>
</dict>
```

Also look up Keyboard-ja.plist, and you see that they use this Roman-Accent-x for almost any character x. But nevertheless, it doesn't work for me if I add it to Keyboard-en.plist. I don't understand why.