# Change characters in press and hold popup? Seems changed in Yosemite?

Tags: keyboard, macos, preferences, internationalization

Does anyone know where the pressandhold.app file is in Yosemite? I used this answer ([How to add characters to the press and hold character picker in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion)) to customize mine, but lost the customizations upon upgrade. Now the System/Library/Input Methods folder is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try searching for it in terminal using the "mdfind -name PressAndHold.app"

Comment: If Input Methods is empty, you are in the wrong Library, namely Library/.  System/Library/Input Methods has over a dozen items including Keyboard Viewer and Character Palette.  You do have those working, right?

Comment: Oops! Thanks! You're so right. I was in the HD Library, where there is an empty /Input Methods/ folder. And I was able to put my altered .plist file in there again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressandhold.app should be in exactly the same place in Yosemite that it was in Mavericks.

I just checked on both my Macs that I upgraded to Yosemite.

`/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app` exists exactly where it should.

And to try to confirm whether this is a holdover from Mavericks (since both my Macs were upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite) I checked the Info.plist with the PressAndHold.app bundle. It lists "10.10" as the LSMinimumSystemVersion and "macosx10.10internal" as the DTSDKName both of which indicate Yosemite.

So please check that folder on your Mac again. I'd be very surprised if that folder was empty.