# How do I change the color in Terminal indicating the use of a dead key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

A dead key (a key that does not generate a complete character by itself but modifies the character generated by the key struck immediately after) is indicated with a yellow background to previous the final character.

[image]

It's perfect when you write black on white, but not when you write white on black, like in some Terminal configurations.

[image]

My question is: Where can I change that color?

Comment: What exactly are dead keys? Can you give an example of a dead key? When I press `command`, `ctrl` or any other modifying key there is no yellow background in my terminal. How do I activate 'dead' keys? Are they part of the text encoding?

Comment: @CousinCocaine I think they mean like accent marks. The way to write é if you don't want to hold down e and then select the character is to press Option-E and then press e.

Comment: @user24601 yes it is (not for accent marks in my case, as I have a French swiss keyboard, but it for greek accent mark)

Comment: I noticed that this is a system wide issue, it is not bound to the Terminal only. Another thing is that this feature is already present in 10.6.8.

Comment: yes, it system wide issue. But the problem appears only on White to Black input...

Comment: Would it be an alternative for you to rather use the accent popup [as described here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155483/accent-popup-in-terminal-app)?

Comment: no, accent popup stop typewriting, and i have to much accent to stop...

Comment: I don't know whether that color can be changed, but I can tell you that it doesn't happen in iTerm2.

Comment: I didn't know it. I will try ;)

Comment: @JayThompson for now iterm2 is doing what I need. I have just to find a French translation.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a clean fix, but here's a work around:

Keep the Terminal as Black on White but then go to:

```
System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Invert Colors
```

Doing this will change your Terminal (and everything else) to White on Black, but also change the yellow dead key to blue.

[image]

---

You can also turn Invert Colors on and off using a keyboard shortcut if you turn it on in the keyboard preferences:

[image]

Comment: indeed, that's not stupid, but as many time I use terminal in the same I use other software I want to be white on black... iterm2 is for now the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

---

**old:** I don't know how to fix the dead keys, but there's a better solution (in my opinion), which avoids dead keys altogether. Check out my answer to the question: [Accent popup in Terminal.app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155483/accent-popup-in-terminal-app/156287#156287).

If you don't like that approach, you might try to dig around in the file `Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` and see if you can find anything there that might be useful.

---

**edit:** *Reading some of the comments on the original question, I see that this solution will not work for the OP, but I will still keep it as an answer in case anyone else might have this question and find the information useful.*