# Greek letter shortcuts in Keynote 6.5

Tags: keynote

I recently switched to Keynote for writing scientific talks. I use tons of greek letters and need a fast way to type them in. I have seen on other questions and forums that people just change the auto-correct settings to replace things like \lambda with the Greek letter. However, in Keynote 6.5 I cant seem to find the auto-correct settings to do this. Its looks like they moved it out of the preferences menu. Anyone know where this is, or have another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Keyboard System Preference, in combination with the Greek keyboard, I was able to get this to work.

Open System Preferences > Keyboard

Select the Keyboard tab and check Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar. The flag of your default language should now appear to the right of the Date/Time menu item.

Select the Input Sources tab > Add Greek keyboard

Select the Text tab > select then add `\lambda` to the Replace field

From the Character Viewer menu bar item, choose the Greek keyboard > Select the With field and type the 'l' key. This should insert the λ character in this field.

[image]

From the Character ViewSwitch back to the default keyboard.

Now, whenever you type `\lambda` you will see this replacement pop-up:

[image]

Repeat with other characters.

Comment: This worked great. Only weird thing for me was when I checked 'Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar', it showed some other symbol that brought up some sort of softKey window. Then when I unchecked this box the American flag popped up and everything worked as described. Maybe due to some other setting I have on somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to modify whichever of  `/System/Library/Input\ Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/PlugIns/PAH_Extension.appex/Contents/Resources/Keyboard*.plist` your keyboard is using.  See also [How to add characters to the press and hold character picker in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion)

Unfortunately, this requires disabling SIP, and you should save a copy to install again every time an OS update cancels your changes.  I updated mine to allow me to easily do [pīnyīn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin) along with a few other Polish/greek/French characters.  But changing the one in `/Library` (not SIP-protected) didn't work, and the one in `/System/Library` was overwritten by the next O.S. update.