# How to select "Press and Hold" characters over 10 characters

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

When I have more than 10 characters in my "Press and Hold" set, I am unable to type 10 or 11 or 12 to select a character. It registers the second keypress. If I type "12", it registers "2" and inserts the character corresponding to "2". This is El Capitan.

Note that I've [modified my English options](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52051/204862) to include Vietnamese characters than I occasionally wish to type, but I assume this would also be a problem if I changed my locale to Vietnam.

[image: Example of selecting from many characters.]

Comment: Click the one you need.

Comment: Yes, also I can use my arrow keys. The UX suggests a faster way though!