# How to sort the special characters menu?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

In order to type special characters, I long press the standard char and then I get a menu to pick exactly the one I need by pressing its number. For example, if I want to type `á` I need to long press `a`, then a menu like the following is displayed, and then I need to hit `2` in order to finally type `á`. However, if I want to type `ó`, the number is `4` instead of `2`.

[image]

I want to know whether it's possible to change the sorting of these characters, so that `á`, `é`, `í`, `ó`, `ú`, `ñ` are all on number `1`.

Comment: Might depend on what language your keyboard is set to - but how about opt/` then the vowel? [that's a backtick, often but not on all languages, next to z] for me that gives me à è ì ò ù in just 2 keystrokes each time.

Comment: oops, wrong accent... opt/e gives acute, sorry - á é í ó ú

Comment: @Tetsujin didn't know that :) still I find less error-prone that menu, so I keep the question open to know whether it's possible to sort it.

Comment: If you check System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard >  "Show Keyboard & Emoji viewer in menu bar" then open the Keyboard viewer from the menu bar & hold opt, you can see all the 'dead keys' you can use to generate accents in the same way -they highlight in orange. This used to be the only method, before the pop-up version was added a few years ago. If you're happy with that method I can add it as an answer...

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd rather the other way, but it's ok, add the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do this by customizing the Accent Menu/Character Picker as described in [this earlier answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion) here: