# Mojave accents on Polish keyboard

Tags: mojave

How to turn on accents menu while holding key `i` or `u` for Polish keyboard?

This feature works well on others keys (`o`, `a`, `n` etc.) and other keyboards.

I use macOS Mojave.

Comment: I guess some shortcut might block the menu for aforementioned characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has never included popup accent menus for i and u on the Polish input sources as far as I know.  To add them you would have to [customize that system](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have tried to update `/System/Library/Input\ Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/PlugIns/PAH_Extension.appex/Contents/Resources/Keyboard-pl.plist` file, but anyways it is not permitted even with sudo, so I copied it to `~/Library`, but apparently it does not work though. Can you give me some tip?

Comment: I used csrutil to disable protection, replaced the file and then enabled back csrutil. It works like a charm! Thanks!