# Long key press: change displayed accent menu content

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

I am often typing in different languages depending on the app I use in MacOS. But I don't want to change input source (i.e., keyboard layout) because it takes time and I would have to revert almost immediately. Moreover, modern MacOS's are able to recognise and correct spelling automatically by language without having to change keyboard layout (System Settings → Keyboard → Spelling → Automatic by Language), which is quite handy.

However, the spelling not being perfect, I have to type correctly some of the word(s). For that I rely on the long key press to "[Use the accent menu](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh27474/13.0/mac/13.0)" or the dead keys. Unfortunately, neither the long press, nor the dead keys offer the diacritical mark I quite often need, in my case the letter ő (LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DOUBLE ACUTE, Unicode: U+0151, UTF-8: C5 91).

Moreover, most of the characters that appear in the long press are useless as they either have a key on my keyboard for them, or I can use the dead keys.

Restrictions:

- I use macOS Ventura (v. 13.6.3);
- Keyboard is CH-FR (Swiss French);
- As noted above, I do not want to change the input source (say from CH-FR keyboard to ABC).

My questions:

- Is there a way to replace one (or more) of the suggested characters that appear in the long key press?
- If yes, how?

Comment: See this earlier answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion?rq=1

Comment: If you switch to the ABC Extended input source, you can make all accents via option dead keys.  Double accute is Option J,  ő

Comment: @TomGewecke. Thanks for your answers. I checked https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/44928/70284, however the solution seems not to apply to macOS Ventura (13.6.3) anymore (that's what I'm using, from OS X Lion referenced in the link). As for the input source, I specified in my OM that I don't want to change it (for the same reason as the user in your link). Will specify all this in my OM.

Comment: I suspect that Apple has made it impossible to do this in Ventura and later, or at least no one has figured it out.  Another work around is to customise ch-fr to add any needed characters with https://software.sil.org/ukelele/