# Where can I find the unicode symbols for Mac functional keys? (Command, Shift, etc.)

Tags: keyboard, unicode

Is there a list of key-symbols that I could reference?

Comment: There's a nice table here: https://acrobatfaq.com/atbref5/index/KeyboardShortcuts/UnicodeCodesforKeyboards.html

Answer (score 196, accepted):

If you are talking about something like this: `&#8984;` (the ⌘ key), then you are looking for this chart:

```
HTML Entity     GLYPH  NAME
&#63743;              Apple
&#8984;         ⌘      Command, Cmd, Clover, (formerly) Apple
&#8963;         ⌃      Control, Ctl, Ctrl
&#8997;         ⌥      Option, Opt, (Windows) Alt
&#8679;         ⇧      Shift
&#8682;         ⇪      Caps lock
&#9167;         ⏏      Eject
&#8617;         ↩      Return, Carriage Return
&#8629; &crarr; ↵      Return, Carriage Return
&#9166;         ⏎      Return, Carriage Return
&#8996;         ⌤      Enter
&#9003;         ⌫      Delete, Backspace
&#8998;         ⌦      Forward Delete
&#9099;         ⎋      Escape, Esc
&#8594; &rarr;  →      Right arrow
&#8592; &larr;  ←      Left arrow
&#8593; &uarr;  ↑      Up arrow
&#8595; &darr;  ↓      Down arrow
&#8670;         ⇞      Page Up, PgUp
&#8671;         ⇟      Page Down, PgDn
&#8598;         ↖      Home
&#8600;         ↘      End
&#8999;         ⌧      Clear
&#8677;         ⇥      Tab, Tab Right, Horizontal Tab
&#8676;         ⇤      Shift Tab, Tab Left, Back-tab
&#9250;         ␢      Space, Blank
&#9251;         ␣      Space, Blank
```

You also can copy the glyphs directly!

Comment: What about the new globe key aka The Artist Formerly Known As `fn`? Which unicode character is that?

Comment:  globe with meridians
Unicode: U+1F310, UTF-8: F0 9F 8C 90

Comment: U+1F310 is not a glyph though, it's an emoji. 

Answer (score 13):

There is no need for third-party apps. Press <kbd>CTR</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the built-in **Characters** popup and use the search field to type the unicode name of the character, e.g.:

- `place of interest` → <kbd>⌘</kbd> *[Command]*
- `option` → <kbd>⌥</kbd> *[Option]*
- `arrowhead` →  <kbd>⌃</kbd> *[Control]*
- `upwards white arrow` →  <kbd>⇧</kbd>  *[Shift]*
- `upwards white arrow from bar` →  <kbd>⇪</kbd>  *[Caps Lock]*

[image: osx Characters popup for unicode special characters]

> ✔️ You can also use it to insert emojis.
>
> Click the top right icon to get the extended version of the dialog.

If you right-click a character the `Get character info` popup will be shown from which you can copy to clipboard the name and the unicode code-point in decimal notation, i.e:

```
⌘ PLACE OF INTEREST SIGN Unicode: U+2318, UTF-8: E2 8C 98
```

To use it in your HTML prepend the unicode entity escape prefix and append the semicolon, i.e. `2318` ⇢ `&#x2318;`.

> You can click the ⚙️ (or 3 dot) button > **Customize List** and enable additional unicode characters groups, including **Code Tables** > **Unicode** which will show the full unicode table grouped by categories. 
>
> The <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇪</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⏎</kbd>  symbols are grouped under the **Technical Symbols** category which you can enable for quick access as shown below.
> [image: macos character viewer Technical Symbols]

Comment: On my Mac (M1 Max MBP) running the latest (12.3), the pop up **can** be tied to the "world" / function key  via System Preferences => Keyboard => Keyboard => Press  to => a drop down list with four options.

Comment: Oh that's a super intuitive name for it: place of interest. I just wasted 20 minutes of my life. Thank you.

Comment: On macOS Ventura (13.6.4). In the menu bar (if you've "show Input menu in menu bar" activated), there's a "Show Emoji & Symbols" option. If you only see emojis, click on the top right icon to switch to the "character viewer" (cf. image in the answer).
![Show Emoji & Symbols](https://i.imgur.com/gPvXROK.png)

Comment: @ccpizza ?!? ‍♂️ Why are you answering that to me? How is that related to what I said? And what you assume is wrong: I don't have multiple input languages (and never talked about that). I pick more often emojis that I switch languages (on my mobile devices). I configure F* to be the defaults and short press Fn as show emojis. I don't have  on my (old) MacBook. What's the difference with Fn?

Answer (score 11):

`Events.h` defines constants for the menu glyphs, but not the code points used to represent them. There are several unofficial lists like [Keyboard icons & terminology - Ask Different Meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/keyboard-icons-terminology?lq=1) or [this one posted on an Apple mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Carbon-dev/2006/Jul/msg00660.html).

CajunLuke rolled back my edit to daviesgeek's answer, so here's another list. Differences compared to the current revision of the other answer:

- Formatted as CSV
- <s>Added ⌧ and ␣</s>
- <s>The numeric character reference for the left arrow key was wrong</s>
- Included [named character references added in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/named-character-references.html#named-character-references)
- Removed uncommon variants like ⏎ and ␢
- The numeric character references are in hexadecimal

```
⌘,&#x2318;,,command
⇧,&#x21e7;,,shift
⌥,&#x2325;,,option
⌃,&#x2303;,,control
↩,&#x21a9;,&hookleftarrow;,return
⌤,&#x2324;,,enter
⌫,&#x232b;,,delete
⌦,&#x2326;,,forward delete
⌧,&#x2327;,,clear
⇥,&#x21e5;,&rarrb;,tab
⇤,&#x21e4;,&larrb;,backtab
␣,&#x2423;,&blank;,space
⎋,&#x238b;,,escape
⇪,&#x21ea;,,caps lock
⏏,&#x23cf;,,eject
⇞,&#x21de;,,page up
⇟,&#x21df;,,page down
↖,&#x2196;,&UpperLeftArrow;,home
↘,&#x2198;,&LowerRightArrow;,end
←,&#x2190;,&larr;,left
→,&#x2192;,&rarr;,right
↑,&#x2191;,&uarr;,up
↓,&#x2193;,&darr;,down
```

Comment: The reason I rolled back your answer was primarily formatting-related. CSV isn't real useful on a webpage. I added the characters you said we missed. (Which we did miss, as I used the screenshot that had been there as a reference.) If I got the number wrong or you want to add the HTML 5 named references, please edit those parts.

Comment: Also, what's better about the hexadecimal versions? (TBH, I didn't know you could do HTML literal references in hex.)

Comment: @CajunLuke Decimal code points are less common in other contexts; for example you can't search for them in Character Viewer. CSV is easier to parse for use in temporary scripts, easier to output, and easier to convert to an HTML table.

Comment: What's better (also) about hexadecimal is that one need not convert to use Apple's "Unicode Hex Input" keyboard to put the character into a document.  All my files (including web pages) are in UTF-8, so using the actual character instead of HTML entities makes my editing more WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the widget...

## [CharacterPal](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/reference/characterpal.html)

- When you hover over a symbol, you can see its coding.
- Copy a symbol to the clipboard by clicking on it. (This will copy the coding.)

The widget offers access to various character sets: *Keyboard*, *Math and Science*, *Greek*, ...

[image]
[image]

Comment: @pcperini You might also be interested in [this awesome tip](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1282/13414) by user stuffe.

Comment: I would also update this with the `control+command+space` shortcut added in OS X also has a "technical" symbols added

Comment: link is broken :(

Comment: @Downgoat, you mean ⌃⌘␣ shortcut? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [TextExpander](https://smilesoftware.com/textexpander) (and if not, why not?! It's only $45. ), you can just import the "[Keyboard](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/downloads/Keyboard.textexpander)" snippet group from [Dr. Drang](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/06/a-couple-of-textexpander-thingies/) (see the second part of the post) and get the symbols you're likely looking for:

```
To insert   Type    Key name  
    ⌘       ;cmd    Command  
    ⌥       ;opt    Option  
    ⇧       ;shift  Shift  
    ⌃       ;ctl    Control  
    ⇥       ;tab    Tab  
    ⌫       ;bs     Backspace  
    ⌦       ;del    Forward Delete  
    ⌅       ;enter  Enter  
    ↩       ;return     Return  
    ⎋       ;esc    Escape  
           ;apple  Apple  
    ←       ;left   Left Arrow  
    →       ;right  Right Arrow  
    ↑       ;up     Up Arrow  
    ↓       ;down   Down Arrow  
    ␣       ;space  Space
```

He also has a few other interesting "set of snippets" you might want to have a look at:

- [Currency icons and Fractions](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/downloads/Numeric.textexpander) - See [here](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/06/a-few-more-simple-textexpander-snippets/) for info.
- [Miscellaneous Symbols](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/downloads/Symbols.textexpander) - see [here](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/06/one-last-set-of-textexpander-symbols/) for info.

Hope this helps!