# Unicode character for Apple special keys?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

Mac keyboards have some unique symbols on their modifier keys such as Cloverleaf and Option.

What are the Unicode values for character representations of these symbols?

Comment: See this question for a short list: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55727/where-can-i-find-the-unicode-symbols-for-mac-functional-keys-command-shift-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this page for a long list:

https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/c5243c4216f1f8cd2251#complete-list