# How can I make a keyboard shortcut for an item with unicode characters?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, shortcut-menu

I have used custom keyboard shortcuts for a long time, and as usual the new version of OSX Yosemite changes all the app translations to make them slightly different enough that none of them work. After going through all the shortcuts I discovered that the Spanish entries for next/previous item in Preview don't work. Here is a screenshot of the menu item:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the option as set up in the keyboard preferences:

[image]

Despite both texts look the same (and therefore I should be able to override the default shortcut) the custom shortcut doesn't get assigned (it did in Mavericks!). My guess is that it stopped working because Yosemite uses a different unicode combination for the first letter. How can I figure out the correct unicode sequence so that the keyboard shortcut is assigned properly?

Answer (score 1):

This is a comparison to mavericks (10.9.5) Preview

[image: preview]

It looks like the only change is the back/forward keyboard shortcuts. Or maybe my Spanish is not up to the snuff.

I am not sure why would you try to make keyboard shortcuts that already exist.

But see this info: [What do I type to produce the command symbol (⌘) in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/4074/46541)

And this info: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_computing_symbols.html

Comment: The arrow substitution might be because [ & ] are not so easy to get to on a Spanish keyboard.

Comment: Well, I customize shortcuts because the defaults don't suit me. I have no problems pressing command on my keyboard and it is not the problem here.

Comment: ⇞ like this after adding keyboard input "Unicode hex Input" and pressing alt shift + 21de  (U+2DE is the Up arrow) the down arrow is U+21DF