# How to type ⌘ on iPad?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, bluetooth

I'm looking for a way to type the Command symbol (⌘) on iPad without installing any third-party apps.

For the moment, when I want to use it, I copy it from [there](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201236) but that's really inconvenient.

##### What I've tried

I first tried most solutions explained in [What do I type to produce the command symbol (⌘) in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/4074) which doesn't involve installing any third-part app, here are the results:

First, I've tried the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/4077).

The issue with the first part is that there is no Character Viewer on iPad as there is in Mac. Then, I tried adding the Unicode Hex Input keyboard layout which wasn't present in *Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard* and in *Settings > Keyboard > Hardware Keyboard* (when using a BT keyboard).

I then tried [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140593) (as well as [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/404273) and [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/118599) which could have been working but did not. I simply don't get any result when searching for *"Place of interest"*. (The following screenshot was taken when searching from a BT keyboard)

[image]

[The answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142819) explaining about how to replace a character in Character Picker unfortunately doesn't work on iPad either since (AFAIK) there is no way to edit plists there.

Of course, text replacement works (see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84825)) but I prefer not to use that as I prefer to be able to write freely (not having a Command symbol when I type "cmd" for example).

---

##### The question

Can I type the Command symbol (⌘) on iPad with the internal or with a Bluetooth keyboard (Keys-To-Go)? If so, how?

<sub>Note that I would also appreciate if the answer also works on iPhone.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

> I'm looking for a way to type the Command symbol (⌘) on iPad without installing any third-party apps.

#### Make a text replacement.

1. Copy the symbol from here (or from the source you referenced).  I’ve referenced some common ones here:

   | Name | Symbol |
   | --- | --- |
   | Command | ⌘ |
   | Option | ⌥ |
   | Return | ⏎ |
   | Backspace | ⌫ |
   | Shift | ⇧ |
   | Caps Lock | ⇪ |
   | Escape | ⎋ |
   | Fn/Globe |  |
   | Apple Logo |  |
   | Eject | ⏏ |
   | Windows Key | ❖ |
   | Meta Key ([Sun/Unix Workstations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key)) | ◆ |

2. Create a text replacement with a shortcut like `scmd` (short for “symbol cmd”). This way, it won’t be inadvertently typed because that phrase is not a dictionary word.
3. Whenever you want the **⌘** symbol, just type “scmd” and it will appear; no third party apps or keyboards necessary.

Comment: From the question: "Of course, text replacement works (see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84825)) but I prefer not to use that as I prefer to be able to write freely (not having a Command symbol when I type "cmd" for example)."

Comment: That’s why you put the “s” in front of cmd.

Comment: I saw that in your answer but as I said, I prefer to use other methods (if there are).

Comment: It’s not part of unicode latin block so you won’t get it.  Either you have to install another keyboard (likely paid) , or you do a text replacement.

Comment: It's weird that it doesn't appear in emojis on iPad though. I'll see if someone comes with something that works other than that. Else I would probably accept this answer.

Comment: @TomGewecke - I searched for a keyboard for a while (prior to this question) and every one I found was a paid keyboard.  There’s likely one out there gratis, but I gave up looking.  I also found that I could use the markdown code like `<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>` with a shortcut, so it became moot.

Comment: Text replacement is by far the easiest way to do this.  You can  use a single character like ^ as the trigger if you want.